# High power boost converter topolgies

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, high-voltage, boost

Recently I got my hands on some big ferrite cores and decided to make a powerful high voltage boost converter I have most of the driver part figured out. I will use a 12 V 10 A power supply and I want to boost that to 350 V 1.5 A. So my question is after researching about boost converters I've found out that there is a lot of boost converter topologies so I picked a few that I think can give me a decent output power.

1. Normal classic boost converter
2. Single switch quadratic boost converter
3. Tapped inductor boost converter

I'm looking forward for opinions on which types of topology will suit my need and why?

Summary: I want to get the maximum power out of it as possible

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

Comment: Aditional info:i want use this boost converter for a qcw Tesla coil in which high pulsed current is is required and for that i will have a 400v 1500uf capacitor for the output filter cap of the boost converter so that the peak current can be supplied by the capacitor and the boost converter is there to charge the capacitor fasf  before the next cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that a simple inductive boost from 12V to 350 as already answered is too much. You would need a 96.5% duty cycle which is really a strain for a converter (usually over 90-95% is a bad idea).

At a first recommendation I'd try with a flyback converter, but at 1.5A it's about 500W so a better idea would be a transformer based  half bridge converter. Not trivial to design anyway.

Comment: alright thank you i will order some EE cores

Comment: I agree. I would look into a forward converter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get 350 V @ 1.5 A if starting from a 12 V 10 A supply.

12V to 350 V is a huge step-up ratio, and difficult to achieve with a classical stage at high power (continuous conduction).

The tapped inductor you have drawn won't work for you as leakage inductance will generate huge spike on the FET and damage it. Adding a snubber (or clamp) at the FET will save it. This is the simplest topology to get working, but will not be very efficient (maybe you'll get 75 %), so will dissipate a lot of heat.

The quadratic converter is difficult to control and is very large for high power levels.

Comment: perhaps will increasing the input voltage can help?because i have power supply than can do 60v 10a maybe

Comment: @Mr.Infinite 60 V input would be _much_ easier.